# P4, How to find changelist user from a given changelist?

Tags: perforce

Anybody knows how to get the change list user from a given changelist(say, #12345)?

p4 describe -s #12345
will give output like this:

**Change #12345 by user@user_clientspec on 2010/07/26 10:26:29

affected files...** 
   
**.......**

Is there any command to give only the user name. Not with client spec as it shows user@user_clientspec.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks, 
Tom

Answer (score 4):

```
p4 change -o 12345 | grep ^User:
```

Or, if you're on a fairly recent version of the 'p4' command line:

```
p4 -F "%User%" -ztag change -o 12345
```

Comment: Nice. This powershell snippet will parse out the actual username, rather than just the line: `p4 change -o 12345 | foreach{if($_ -match "^User:\w*(.*)") {$matches[1].Trim()}}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll just have to parse the output.

This ungainly bit of powershell will get you the user:

```
p4 describe -s 12345 | select-object -first 1 | %{ $_.Split()[3].Split('@')[0] }
```

Answer (score 0):

to get only the user, and not other "User:" strings, trailing spaces, etc. try:

```
bash -c "p4 change -o 12345 | grep -oP '(?<=^User:).*' | xargs"
```